# SQL SubQueries syntax

Tags: sql, subquery

I am working on a problem that involves a sub select query. I have the databases set up in order to get the select query to work, but I'm relatively new to these subqueries and am a little lost. I need return band name and album titles of said bands with more than 1 album.  Here is my code so far.

```
SELECT b.Name, a.Title
FROM Band as b, Album as a
WHERE (SELECT * 
       FROM Album as al
       WHERE al.BID = a.BID)
GROUP BY b.Name
HAVING Count(a.BID) > 1;
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Why don't people read the documentation? It is explained in there!

Comment: What SQL product are you using?

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
SELECT b.Name, a.Title 
FROM Band b 
INNER JOIN Album a ON b.BID=a.BID
WHERE a.BID IN (SELECT BID FROM Album GROUP BY BID HAVING COUNT(BID)>1)
```

This will work given that `Album` table has a `BID` as a foreign key for `Band` table

Comment: Seeing as I created the tables and the data within them, I know that it should return 1 band, and that band's 3 albums...It's doing neithe. Even with this code.

Comment: share the schema for these 2 tables (what columns they have), this will help in answering the question

Comment: Your code returned all the bands and their album, I'm trying to find only the bands that have more than 1 album.

Comment: sorry, misunderstood your question, thought you'd need to return all bands that have at least 1 album... here, I edited my answer, take a look

Comment: No problem, glad it helped! Also, if the answer helped you please get into habit of accepting answers otherwise people will not be helping you anymore if they see you're not doing it...